# jest-haste-map: @providesModule naming collision

Tags: node.js

when i run npm start or react-native start ,i got this warning:

```
jest-haste-map: @providesModule naming collision:
  Duplicate module name: core-js
  Paths: {path_to_project}/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/core-js/package.json collides with {path_to_project}/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/fbjs/node_modules/core-js/package.json

This warning is caused by a @providesModule declaration with the same name across two different files.
jest-haste-map: @providesModule naming collision:
  Duplicate module name: base64-js
  Paths: {path_to_project}/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/base64-js/package.json collides with {path_to_project}/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/simple-plist/node_modules/base64-js/package.json

This warning is caused by a @providesModule declaration with the same name across two different files.
```

and here is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "ProjectName",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "chroma-js": "^1.3.4",
    "crypto-js": "^3.1.9-1",
    "mobile-center": "^0.7.0",
    "mobile-center-analytics": "^0.7.0",
    "mobile-center-crashes": "^0.7.0",
    "mobx": "^3.1.10",
    "mobx-react": "^4.1.8",
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-addons-shallow-compare": "^15.5.2",
    "react-mixin": "^2.0.2",
    "react-native": "^0.45.1",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.2.2",
    "react-native-baidu-map": "^0.6.0",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-root-toast": "^1.1.2",
    "react-native-smart-splash-screen": "^2.3.4",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.2.0",
    "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.11",
    "react-timer-mixin": "^0.13.3",
    "realm": "^1.10.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "20.0.3",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "2.0.0",
    "jest": "20.0.4",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0-alpha.12"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

and my dev environment is:

```
node: v6.11.2
npm: 3.10.10
os: macOS Sierra
```

i have tried any way, such as update RN version, clear watchMan cache, specified all dependencies's version, adjusted devDependencies's version like babel-jest's version, but all of it does not work. i don't know what is wrong, i need help. or whether it is a issue.

anything is appreciate!

Comment: i just delete the 'node_modules' folder which under the folder 'fbjs' and floder 'simple-plist', and the warning gone.

Answer (score 0):

probably you've generate your project with a name and then you changed the `name` property in your `package.json` to a different name.

check the `app.json` and `package.json` files to see if you have the same project name across all files of you application